# PowerShell and Service Manager

Tags: powershell, system-center

I want to pull some information and Incidents from the Service manager through PowerShell, I'm using the command:

`Get-SCSMClassInstance -Class (Get-SCSMClass -Name System.WorkItem.Incident) -Filter 'Id -eq "IR1131310"'`

However, the data that I really need (to filter) does not appear in the powershell imports, in fact there are 2, Site and Classification category:

[image]

Is there any method for me to pull the information?
Thanks